# React - Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object called SelectedMovie that is passed as a prop to my component.
The SelectedMovie has an attribute called moviePoster that is an Object and has an attribute called imageUrl.

When I'm trying to display the imageUrl attribute, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imageUrl')
movieDetailsWithScheduledMovies
C:/Users/User/Documents/GitHub/ddd_cinema/frontend/src/components/Movie/MovieDetails/movieDetailsWithScheduledMovies.js:23
  20 | </h5>
  21 | <br/>
  22 | <div className={"col-md-4"}>
> 23 |     <img src={props.selectedMovie.moviePoster.imageUrl} height={"540px"}></img>
     | ^  24 | </div>
  25 | <div className={"col-md-8"}>
  26 |     <p>{props.selectedMovie.trailerUrl}</p>
```

This is my component:

```js
import React from "react";
import './movieDetailsWithScheduledMovies.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const movieDetailsWithScheduledMovies = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className={"container mm-4 mt-5"}>
            <div className={"row"}>
                <div className={"table-responsive"}>
                    <div className={"row"}>

                        <div className={"row"}>
                            <h1 className={"text-dark nameOfMovie"}>
                                {props.selectedMovie.name}
                                ({props.selectedMovie.genre})
                            </h1>
                            <h5 className={"mt-3"}>
                                {props.selectedMovie.description}
                            </h5>
                            <br/>
                            <div className={"col-md-4"}>
                                <img src={props.selectedMovie.moviePoster.imageUrl} height={"540px"}></img>
                            </div>
                            <div className={"col-md-8"}>
                                <p>{props.selectedMovie.trailerUrl}</p>
                                <iframe width="900" height="300" src={props.selectedMovie.trailerUrl}>
                                </iframe>
                                <br/>
                                <div className={"row"}>
                                    <p>Book tickets:</p>
                                    {props.scheduledMovies.map((term) => {

                                        return (
                                            <div className={"col"}>
                                                <Link className={"btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark"}
                                                    onClick={() => props.onBookTickets(term.id.id)}
                                                    to={`/ticket/makeNewReservation/${term.id.id}`}>
                                                    Monday, {term.dateAndTimeScheduled.hour}:{term.dateAndTimeScheduled.minutes}
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </div>

                                <div className={"row"}>
                                    <p>Similar movies:</p>
                                    {props.similarMovies.map((term) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div className={"col"}>
                                                {term.name}
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default movieDetailsWithScheduledMovies;
```

When I comment out the part that is causing the issue, all of the remaining attributes of the object work fine.

The same attribute (imageUrl) works fine in a different component where I have a list of Movies:

```js
<Link
                        onClick={() => {
                            props.onDetails(term.id.id);
                            props.onFetchScheduledMoviesByMovieId(term.id.id)
                        }}
                        to={`/movie/fetchScheduledMoviesByMovieId/${term.id.id}`}>
                        <img className={"mt-1 mb-1"} src={term.moviePoster.imageUrl} height={"200px"}
                             width={"136px"}></img>
                    </Link>
```

Edit: I printed the selectedMovie in console, and moviePoster is fine there. This is the response in console:
[image]

Comment: If you console.log is it still undefined?

Comment: Where should I console.log? I am a bit new to react.

Comment: @m_kr let us see the structure of the object called `SelectedMovie`

Comment: ^@m_kr comment out the part that is causing the issue, and `console.log(props.selectedMovie)` before `return(...`

Comment: console.log(selectedMovie)

Comment: Try to use like this => `<img src={props?.selectedMovie?.moviePoster?.imageUrl} ...`

Comment: I printed selectedMovie in console.log, like @Rukshan suggested, and everything is fine, it's not null.

Comment: It depends on when the component is rendered. If you are getting the movie information through network call, then when you component is rendered for the first time, your "selectedMovie" might be still empty object. So your react component will fail to render. Later it might be filled with data, that's when you might see it in console.log()

See if you always have "selectedMovie" information or there are some situations when it might not be there even for a few milli seconds.

Comment: @SumanthKumarMora but everything else is loaded just fine. If scheduledMovie was empty, wouldn't it's other attributes be issues as well?

Comment: @German I posted an edit in my project where I print the selectedMovie object in console. Is that enough for the structure?

Comment: @m_kr, No. Others will work well, beacause "selectedMovie.moviePoster.imageUrl" is the only place where you have nested object. I meant, probably "selectedMovie.trailerUrl" can return undefined and which is okay for React. But in the first case "selectedMovie.moviePoster" return undefinted and when you do "undefinted.imageUrl" that creates problem.

Comment: @SumanthKumarMora looks like that's the issue. Is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: React can still render if the provided value is "undefined" but when we try to do "undefined.xxx" it will fail. Which could be the case in your scenario. When you try to do "selectedMovie.moviePoster.imageUrl" -> it might become "undefined.imageUrl" and that breaks.

Comment: Yes you can. Please use ternary operator to make sure you never do "undefinted.xxxx". For example {selectedMovie.moviePoster ? selectedMovie.moviePoster.imageUrl: ""} something like this. Any way of conditional code will solve this

Comment: @SumanthKumarMora this solved my issue. Thank you. You can post this as an answer if you want so I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: Sure, will do. Good to know it was the issue :)

Comment: @m_kr It's a broken Image I cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failure of component because of props depends on when the component is rendered. If you are getting the movie information through network call, in that case, when your component is rendered for the first time, your `selectedMovie` might be still `empty object {}`. So your react component will fail to render. Later it might be filled with data, that's when you might see it in `console.log()`. Check if you are always having `selectedMovie` information or there are some situations when it might not be there even for a few milli seconds.

If it is not rendered because the data is not available. You can use ternary operations like `{selectedMovie.moviePoster ? selectedMovie.moviePoster.imageUrl: ""}` to avoid doing something like `undefined.xxxx` which can lead to **Cannot read properties of undefined**